# Reasons for using (isLoading or isFetching) in react-query

Tags: reactjs, react-query

I am a user who uses react.
I didn't use the isloading function well while using react-query.
In terms of ui, I thought that is loading was used to show the loading screen to the user.
I thought I didn't have to show loading because the data fetch is fast.

But suddenly, this thought occurred to me.

If you hand over props to a child component, after the data passes 'undefined' and gets fetching, you often render the fetch data, so I thought it might be because of the reason for optimizing rendering, or is there another reason?

Answer (score 12):

I think your question deserves a slightly more detailed answer because `isFetching` is very often ignored.

## isLoading

As you discovered a query can be fetched fast enough that you might feel you do not need to check for `isLoading`. In many examples you will see something like this:

```
  const { data, isLoading } = useQuery(...);

  if (isLoading)
    return <div>Loading...</div>;

  return <DataTable data={data} />;
```

While the data is being fetched the first time (`UseQueryResult.status === "loading"`) you display a *loading indicator* of some sort and when the data is available you can use it as you please.

### Delayed loading indicator

If the query is fast to load then you'll briefly see "Loading..." (or a spinner) and that's not a good UI. For very short delays it's better to display nothing at all: you can do it with an animation (or setting a timer to make the spinner visible), it does not really matter as long as you embed this in your `<LoadingIndicator />` component. I found that a 100/150 ms delay is a good compromise (for me). Out there there are studies to determine what the most appropriate value is, if you're interested.

### Errors

You probably want to also handle errors, there is `isError` for that (alternatively you can simply use `status` for everything). A slightly more complicate typical implementation will look like this:

```
const { status, data, error, refresh } = useQuery(...);

if (status === "loading")
  return <LoadingIndicator />;

if (status === "error" />
  return <Error error={error} onRetry={refresh} />

return <DataTable data={data} onRefresh={refresh} />;
```

Note how we introduced `refresh()`, when we call it we will cause `isFetching` to be `true` (which does not happen for the initial fetch).

## isFetching

As we saw, `isFetching` is `true` when we already have a value (or attempted a first fetch) and we're fetching the same data again. This is true when we *manually* trigger a refresh but also when react-query is re-loading cached data (in this case `status === "success"`).

This is very important in few cases:

- We might not want to show a loading indicator when refreshing the table.
- When `isRefresh` is `true` and `data !== undefined` we may want to simply disable editing (where supported) without showing any loading indicator (or using a different subtler one).

We might also want to display stale data using a subtle visual clue (for example dimming the text), if nothing changed then we'll have minimum flickering and layout changes when fresh data is available. See also `isPreviousData`.

## Reuse

As you can see you will probably have a lot of boilerplate code around a simple query. What I like to do is to build one reusable component:

```
const query = useQuery(...);

return (
  <Query query={query}>
    ({ data }) => <DataTable data={data} />
  </Query>
);
```

### Accessibility

Do not forget to include `aria-live` and `aria-busy` attributes, the outer container (parent for the data and the loading/error indicators) could be, for example, be defined like this:

```
<section aria-live="polite" aria-busy={isLoading || isFetching}>
```

Exact implementation depends on your specifics but do not forget to include ARIA attributes also for the loading indicator (especially if using animations/icons):

```
<div role="alert" aria-live="polite" aria-label="Loading" />
```

and for the error *banner* you may include `role="alert"` (in this case the default `aria-live="assertive"` implied by the `"alert"` role is appropriate).

Comment: One reason to use `isFetching` rather than `isLoading` is because of react-query's devs' bizarre decision to make `isLoading` `true` when a query is disabled.

Answer (score 0):

I think you hit the nail on the head with some of that.

There is a brief bit of time when your data is undefined which means some of your code might break.

A very simple example

```
const MyComponent = () => {
  const { data, loading } = useQuery(..)

  if (loading) return <LoadingComponent />

  return (<table> { data.map((item) => <tr>{item.name}</tr>)} </table>)
}
```

if data is undefined then data.map will break. However you are making a point that you could just check if data exists.

`if (!data) return <LoadingComponent/>`

But! if your query errored out then data will be undefined and you will be stuck in loading forever when really you should throw an error message.

So you could make use of the error prop to get around that too

```
  const { data, error } = useQuery(..)

  if !(data || error) return <LoadingComponent />
```

Now you don't have all that much use for loading, except maybe if you want to let your user know that your data is updating in the background, if you already have cached data.

Eg lets say you've called the query already, and reactquery populates the data using the cache immediately, but its doing a background check to make sure the cached data is up to date, then you can use the loading prop to show a little spinner that your data is syncing!

Comment: adding error in the if that returns `LoadingComponent` will also cause the user to get stuck. You'd better have a second if that returns an error message like `if (error) return <ErrorComponent />`