# How can I change the isLoading state to true in React Query when a refetch is triggered?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-query

When refetchCompanies is triggered, I want to set the isLoadingCompanies state to true so this component will re-render. I only want to render the component when isLoadingCompanies is true, and not when isFetchingCompanies is true.

My object:

```
const {
    isLoading: isLoadingCompanies,
    isFetching: isFetchingCompanies,
    data: dataCompanies,
    refetch: refetchCompanies
} = useQuery(
    "queryCompanies",
    () => companySearchQuery(currentPage, searchTerm, token)
)
```

Component:

```
<div>
    {(!isLoadingCompanies) && companies?.map((company, index) => (
        <h3>{company?.name}</h3>
    ))}  
    {isLoadingCompanies && <LoadingDataSpinner/>}
</div>
```

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75401670/1207195

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How can I change the isLoading state to true in React Query when a refetch is triggered?

The simple answer is: you can't. A query will be in `loading` state if it's fetching and has no data. So, during a refetch, given that you already have data, your query will *not* be in `loading` state.

To display a loading spinner for background refetches, you can look at the `isFetching` value retuned from `useQuery`, which will be `true` whenever any fetch is happening, not matter if it's the first fetch or a refetch. You can also use `isRefetching` to only check for refetches happening.